# TypeError: Text reading control character must be a single unicode character or None

Tags: python, numpy

Using `numpy.loadtxt` with `numpy==1.23.4` is throwing a `TypeError` when loading from a file with multiple characters in the delimiter:

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

csv_file = StringIO("""1||2
3||4
5||6
""")

print(np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter="||"))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hayesall/Teaching/questions/nploadtxt/testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter="||"))
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/debug/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1318, in loadtxt
    arr = _read(fname, dtype=dtype, comment=comment, delimiter=delimiter,
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/debug/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 979, in _read
    arr = _load_from_filelike(
TypeError: Text reading control character must be a single unicode character or None; but got: '||'
```

With `numpy==1.22.4` this does not appear to happen:

```
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]
 [5. 6.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadtxt` [appears to have been rewritten](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22311#issuecomment-1251651096) between `1.22` and `1.23`.

One fix would be to replace `np.loadtxt` with `np.genfromtxt`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

csv_file = StringIO("""1||2
3||4
5||6
""")

print(np.genfromtxt(csv_file, delimiter="||"))
```